# Backward Kolmogorov equation to find probability

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, markov-process, stochastic-differential-equations

From lecture notes in a course on SDE's. We are tasked with using the backward Kolmogorov equation to find.

$\mathbb{P}^{X_t=x}\left(X_T\geq2 \right)$

I am confused by the terminology here. We are looking for the probability that a process at time $t$ is equal to $x$, conditioned on the terminal value being equal to $2$. Do we then solve for the density in the backward equation and  integrate over the time interval?

Comment: $P^{X_t=x}(X_T\ge 2)$ denotes the probability that $X_T\ge 2$ given $X_t=x$ (not the probability that $X_t=x$ given $X_T\ge 2$).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I would then solve for the density in the backwards equation, which would give me a probability density $k(x,t)$, expressed as a function of the initial conditions. Would I then just integrate the relevant area in the probability space?